# ASP.NET C# Response.Write doesn't display message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am told just by using Javascript inside the Response.Write method, I can display an alert/message box on ASP.NET C#.

Using `Response.Write("<script>alert('Data inserted successfully')</script>")` as the template given in other answers.

When I first attempted to use it, it worked, displaying the message and redirecting me sucessfully. Since then, it has not worked, I only changed the message to display and also where the redirect URL would go after. Logically it is working as it is taking me back to the application form, it just isn't displaying the message.

Can anyone explain why it suddenly doesn't work?

Code;

```
        public ActionResult UpdateApplication(int ApplicationId, ApplicationEdit applicationEdit)
    {
        if(applicationEdit.Firm == false)
        try
        {
            applicationService.UpdateApplication(applicationEdit, ApplicationId);
            return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { ApplicationId = applicationEdit.ApplicationId });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Sorry, You can only have 1 firm application to send off, please update the old application and untick firm option on other application first.')</script>");
            return RedirectToAction("UpdateApplication", new { ApplicationId = applicationEdit.ApplicationId });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't `Response.Write` and `Redirect` in one step. If the server returns 302 redirect, the page body is ignored by the browser. I doubt it ever worked.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I see my mistake, thank you! I just need to return the view, no need to redirect, not sure why I didn't see this

Answer (score 1):

Because you're redirecting the user:

```
return RedirectToAction("UpdateApplication", new { ApplicationId = applicationEdit.ApplicationId });
```

This returns a redirect HTTP code to the browser (HTTP 307 or 308 I imagine) which tells the browser to direct the user to the specified URL.  Since the browser knows it's redirecting the user, it has no reason to render any content in the response.

Either return content to be rendered in the browser *or* return a redirect response, but not both.  If you return the view instead then you should see your `<script>` element in the resulting response.  If you want to redirect then any message you want to display to the user should be on that next page, not in the current response.

---

As an aside, using `Response.Write` in an ASP.NET MVC application is *pretty much always* the wrong approach.  Any client-side code should be in or referenced by the view, and you can use data on the view's model to conditionally render or not render that content.

Comment: I realised that I didn't need to redirect as you stated. Just needed to return the view to update the application which I now have working. I did read up on why using Response.Write is bad and is better to create a class for the message box. I will try to implement that when I feel comfortable to do so. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Just to node that ASP redirects are 302s rather than 307. 308 is a permanent redirect.